# How to bind an <details> element's open attribute in Ember?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have some onboarding steps that are part of a workflow. These steps are contained within a `<details>` element that I have open by default the first time they visit. To close the details panel, a user can either click a button acknowledging they understand the steps or simply click the `<summary>` element which is default behaviour for details elements.

```
<details open={{not isOnboarded}}>
  <summary>Getting Started</summary>
  <p>some steps about getting started</p>

  <button type="button" {{action 'completeOnboarding'}}>I Understand</button>
</details>
```

Unfortunately, because of the fact that the `<details>` element toggles the `open` attribute natively, it seems to be removing Ember's binding.

How can I bind the details opening in Ember?

Comment: I've been playing around, and it seems quite tricky. you *could* do it, but probably its easier to just not use an `<details>` but do it in ember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember stores the state (`isOnboarded`) in memory and re-renders DOM whenever the state changes. However, Ember does not check up on DOM to reconcile the state. Note that this is not a limitation of Ember, most js framework also work like this. Constant reconciliation of DOM is not computationally viable.

You can prevent the default behavior and use Ember to toggle it instead.

**controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  isOpen: true,
  actions: {
    toggleDetails () {
        this.toggleProperty('isOpen')
    },
    onNativeToggle (e) {
      // e here is the native HTMLEvent
      e.preventDefault()
      this.send('toggleDetails') // triggers the 'toggleDetails' action
    }
  }
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
<details open={{isOpen}} onclick={{action 'onNativeToggle'}}>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>

<button onclick={{action 'toggleDetails'}}> Click to Toggle via Ember </button>
```

An Ember Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/65a4cffe7e8fb8bcf41ff7064cc6d524?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C